# Search values in dataframe by condition on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to get the value in column A for the closest value in column B for each multiple of 'trigger'

for instance, in the dataframe below :

```
import random

trigger = 100

info2 = {'A': [0]*100,'B': [0]*100}
dfA = pd.DataFrame(info2)


for i in range(1, len(dfA)):
    dfA.loc[i,'B'] = i*3.78
    dfA.loc[i,'A'] = i*10

    
dfA
```

[image]

Since the closest value to trigger*1 would be 98.28 from row n°26
The closest value to trigger*2 would be 200.34 from row n°53
The closest value to trigger*3 would be 298.62 from row n°79

The expected result would be :
result = [260,530,790]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

trigger = 100

info2 = {'A': [0]*100,'B': [0]*100}
dfA = pd.DataFrame(info2)

for i in range(1, len(dfA)):
    dfA.loc[i,'B'] = i*3.78
    dfA.loc[i,'A'] = i*10

result = []
for t in np.arange(trigger, trigger*4, trigger):
    idx = (np.abs(dfA['B'] - t)).idxmin()
    result.append(dfA.loc[idx, 'A'])

print(result)
```

which gives what you expected.

Comment: This is however not very efficient O(n*m) complexity when you can achieve O(n) ;)

Answer (score 1):

This could do

```
import numpy as np
triggers = {'100': 100, '200': 200, '300': 300}
for k, v in triggers.items():
    dfA['delta_val'] = np.abs(dfA['B'] - v)
    triggers[k] = dfA[dfA.delta_val == dfA.delta_val.min()]['A'].values[0]
print(triggers)

# {'100': 260, '200': 530, '300': 790}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
difference = abs(dfA - target)
min_index = difference.sum(axis=1).idxmin()
result = dfA.loc[min_index, :]
print(result)
```

Comment: difference = abs(dfA - target)
min_index = difference.sum(axis=1).idxmin()
result = dfA.loc[min_index, :]
print(result)

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html#pandas.merge_asof):

```
pd.merge_asof(pd.Series(np.arange(trigger, dfA['B'].max(), trigger), name='B'),
              dfA, on='B', direction='nearest')
```

*NB. dfA must first be sorted on B.*

Output:

```
       B    A
0  100.0  260
1  200.0  530
2  300.0  790
```

If you also want the value of B:

```
pd.merge_asof(pd.Series(np.arange(trigger, dfA['B'].max(), trigger), name='trigger'),
              dfA, left_on='trigger', right_on='B', direction='nearest')
```

Output:

```
   trigger    A       B
0    100.0  260   98.28
1    200.0  530  200.34
2    300.0  790  298.62
```